# foreach syntax missing endcs.., tex cap exceeded

Tags: foreach, syntax

I want to draw points in a loop. x and y coordinates are given ( two variables). I think it is syntactically right, but tikz dont. Can anyone help?

mwe:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{% for turning direction of an arrow tip, man p203
               }
\usepackage[paperheight=160mm,
            paperwidth=180mm,
            top=5mm,
            bottom=5mm,
            left=5mm,
            right=5mm,
           ]{geometry}
\tikzset{%
  inner sep=0pt,%
  outer sep=2pt,%
  mark coordinate/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=00pt,}%mark=x}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% All Points
let \c={0};
\foreach \px/\py  in {%
   0/4,
   1.9/5.92,     
   1.9/5.363,
   0.56/4.0,%           
  }{%
   let \c={\c+1};
   \coordinate[mark coordinate,] (p\c) at (\px,\py);
   \node[rotate=45,label={[left]{\tiny p\c}}] at (p\c) {\tiny{+}};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the usual problem: `\foreach` executes each cycle in a group, so your `let\c=\c+1` gets forgotten as soon as this group ends.

You can use `count=\c` instead (`/pgf/foreach/count`, page 1005 of the manual).

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  inner sep=0pt,
  outer sep=2pt,
  mark coordinate/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt,}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% All Points
\foreach \px/\py [count=\c] in {%
   0/4,
   1.9/5.92,
   1.9/5.363,
   0.56/4.0
  }{%
   \coordinate[mark coordinate,] (p\c) at (\px,\py);
   \node[label={[left]{\tiny p\c}}] at (p\c) {\tiny$\times$};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Using `$\times$` is better than rotating a +.

[image]

Comment: awkward error msgs, thank you. The fifth point (not wished) vanishes when eliminating the last comma in the list.

Comment: @gizeh Oh, yes! I'll update the picture.